# How can I get MultivaluedSection values from Eureka?

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I've searched and cannot find an answer that addresses this particular issue.

I'm using Eureka in Swift 4.1 and want to store these values into another array.

How can I get the values selected here?

```
MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Insert, .Delete],
                           header: "Primary Instrument") {
            $0.tag = "instruments"
            $0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { _ in
                ActionSheetRow<String> {
                    $0.title = "Tap to Select"
                    $0.options = ["Vocals", "Guitar", "Bass", "Keyboards", "Ukelele"]
                }
            }
            $0 <<< ActionSheetRow<String> {
                $0.title = "Tap to Select"
                $0.options = ["Vocals", "Guitar", "Bass", "Keyboards", "Ukelele"]
            }
        }
```

The following method does not work for MultivaluedSection:

```
if let items = self.form.rowBy(tag: "instruments") as? MultivaluedSection
            {
                print(items.values())
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always did it like this:

```
let values: [String]? = (form.sectionBy(tag: "instructions")?.flatMap { ($0 as? ActionSheetRow<String>)?.value })
```

Basically,

- get the section with the tag
- try to convert each row into a `ActionSheetRow<String>`
- map each row that can be converted to its value.

Comment: Thank you for posting... however, all I get is 'nil'.

Comment: Here is my code: let values: [String]? = (self.form.sectionBy(tag: "instructions")?.compactMap { ($0 as? ActionSheetRow<String>)?.value })   print(values) shows 'nil'

Comment: How can I get the values out?

Comment: @LarrySeyer oops, it should be "instruments" not "instructions". Also, "flatMap", not "compactMap".

Comment: That did it!  Thanks very much!

Comment: As an FYI... I had to add self. to form and it works using this line:   let values: [String]? = (self.form.sectionBy(tag: "instruments")?.flatMap { ($0 as? ActionSheetRow<String>)?.value })

Comment: @LarrySeyer if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark!

Comment: Done!  I’m not familiar with how stack overflow works.  Sorry.